# Как чередовать вывод информации в c#?

Tags: c#

Есть 9 кнопок, при нажатии на произовльную кнопку(при условии, что все остальные пустые) ставится текст "Х" на неё.Если выбрать след.произвольную кнопку, должен поставиться текст "0".Дальше 3-ю проивзольную кнопку, ставится "Х". Как это можно чередовать ?

```
 var buttons = new[] { Resource.Id.button1,
                              Resource.Id.button2,
                              Resource.Id.button3,
                              Resource.Id.button4,
                              Resource.Id.button5,
                              Resource.Id.button6,
                              Resource.Id.button7,
                              Resource.Id.button8,
                              Resource.Id.button9}.Select(b => FindViewById<Button>(b)).ToList();


        void buttonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clicked = sender as Button;
            if (clicked.Text == "")
            {
                clicked.Text = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                clicked.Text = "0";
            }

        }


        for (var i = 0; i<9; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].Click += new EventHandler(buttonHandler);
        }
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос Ваши попытки самостоятельного решения (пусть и неудачные). А, то вопрос выглядит как очередное "решите мне задачку".

Comment: добавил к теме.

Answer (score 2):

Решается через флаг.

```
private bool isCross { get; set; }
```

А дальше по коду:

```
if (clicked.Text == "")
{
    clicked.Text = isCross ? "X" : "0";
    isCross = !isCross; // не забываем поменять состояние флага
}
```